# Checking if a value exists in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

This is my data:

```
  A           B           C
-----       -----       ----
27020       27020        ""
27021       27021        ""
27022       27025       27022
27023       27026       27023
27024       27027       27024
```

IF A1 exists in column B then C = empty row.

IF A2 not exists in column B then C = value of A2

How can I do this in Excel 2013?

Comment: Try looking up into `VLOOKUP`. When you use an `IF` or `IFERROR`, you'll get your desired output.

Comment: I tried but it give me always errors

Comment: Could you give the formula you tried please? I might be able to help you identify where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple `IF-COUNTIF` check.

[image]

Formula in `C1`, dragged down to suit:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,B:B)>0,"",A1)
```

Comment: Very true. A `SUMPRODUCT` variation would be better in longer ranges.

Comment: Not really. `SUMPRODUCT` is _even_ slower.

Comment: Hm. Against `COUNTIF`, perhaps. But against `IF-COUNTIF`, what's the comparison? Still the latter?

Comment: A single `IF` does not really need much processing. `COUNTIF` and `IF-COUNTIF` should be almost identical.

Comment: Nice to know that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup is the way to go. Enter the following in cell C2:

=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$6,1,FALSE),"",0),A2)

Comment: Sorry, if the first cell with data is A1, enter the formula in C1